# Automatically changing google search pages

Tags: python, google-chrome, web-scraping, automation

so I want to figure out how to automatically change google search pages with python
[image]

these are what I mean.
The problem that I have is the url's when changing don't really have a pattern what I mean is this
[image]

so Im guessing I have to find some sort of function that automatically finds the correct url for the next page but Im not even sure if thats doable or not.
my question is is it even possible to do this and if it is where should I start how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use the Selenium library for this job, read this link:

https://realpython.com/modern-web-automation-with-python-and-selenium/